# Multivariate multiple regression - individual predictors are significant, but overall model isn't?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, model

I'm testing a number of ideology scales for IVs and seeing how they predict a number of well-being scale DVs. Turns out that my ideology scales individually seem to predict well-being, but when taken together, they don't, as the lack of fit table shows a Pillai's trace for the combined effect on the DVs as non-significant (p =.544).

I'm struggling to understand why this is, and what I should do about it. I've tested the assumptions and there doesn't seem to be any multicollinearity, and the sample size is fairly large (~400). One thing that comes to mind is that the ideologies basically measure separate, opposing things, and so one of the predictors has a positive association with well-being, and the other has a negative association. Is it possible that they're 'cancelling eachother out' and this is the problem? Or is that nonsense? Are the individual predictors still relevant, or does the lack of model fit ruin everything?

Any guidance would be much appreciated!